# Django admin many to many table name

Tags: django, django-admin

Can I specify the name I want for the many to many table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See [Table Names](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names) for all of the exciting details.

**Update:** OK, then perhaps the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) option is what you are looking for. There are some caveats [covered here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).

**Updatex2:** OK, Kelvin gets a star for answering his own question! It's been an age since I perused the [Django Meta Model Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/), but, in retrospect, that's where we should have started.

BTW, wandering through the `django/db/` code on only half a cup of coffee is *definitely* a challenge.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to specify the table name of the many to many field.

Comment: +1 for the related_name. Its also good to point out that the naming syntax has changed in 1.2 http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name

Comment: I was actually thinking that the though argument would let you specify the name of the m2m table and related_name just lets you name the backwards lookup.

Comment: Sigh, I guess I can't win today. Remember, Kids, this is what happens when you answer questions after a couple of beers.

Comment: Solved, use db_table for the ManyToManyField.

Answer (score 2):

You define the table name using the `db_table` option when declaring the `ManyToManyField` attribute. See example below:

```
class revision(models.Model):
    revision_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    issue_list = models.ManyToManyField(issue, related_name='revisions', db_table='issue_revision')
```

`related_name` is the field by which this class will be seen by `issue`, meaning, you will access it as `my_issue.revisions()`. And the table being used in the DB is named `issue_revision`.

Answer (score 0):

[msb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62648527/18024965) works great,
**however if (like me) you needed to set it to the same name** (because of [known naming issues](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#table-names) mysql-django backend), you would need to register it in a migration.

The new problem is that Django will try to create a new table of the same name when you run the automatically created new migrations, which will throw a "database already exists" error.

You would thus need to go back to the original migration where that `ManyToManyField` was created and add what you included there.

### For example:

`app/models.py`:

```py
class revision(models.Model):
    revision_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    issue_list = models.ManyToManyField(issue, related_name='revisions', db_table='app_revision_issue_list')

# In here, 'app_revision_issue_list' was originally created automatically, 
# however lets say you need to explicitly declare it (compatible across all environments)
```

`app/migrations/0003_.py`:

```py
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='revision',
            fields=[
                ('revision_id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('issue_list', models.ManyToManyField(issue, related_name='revisions', db_table='app_revision_issue_list')), 
                # originally no db_table parameter in this migration operation
            ],
        ),
```

If you edit the original migration where the field was created, there is no further need to `makemigrations` and `migrate`.